# Get all items from a list using javascript filter method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to filter items from the list. When a certain category will be provided as a value to the target variable, the filter method should return only items with that category. but when no category is provided I want to get items of all categories regardless of category. In my code below works ok, but I want more clear logic to filter items when no category is provided as a target.

```
let items = [
  {'name':"A",'category':"a"},
  {'name':"B",'category':"b"},
  {'name':"C",'category':"c"}
]
let target;
console.log(items.filter( item => {
    if(target==undefined){
    return true;
  }
    return (item['category']===target);
}));
```

Comment: You didn't take any of my other suggestions in your code view posting.  Turn this into a function.  Tell us what the inputs are to that function and describe what you want the outputs to be for different inputs.  This is still not a clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coiuld filter by either no category or with the category.

```js
const
    filter = (data, category) => data.filter(o => !category || o.category === category),
    items = [{ name: "A", category: "a" }, { name: "B", category: "b" }, { name: "C", category: "c" }];

console.log(filter(items));
console.log(filter(items, 'a'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function that takes a list of items and an optional `target`. In case a target was passed return the filtered list, otherwise, return the list itself:

```js
const filterByCategoryIfTargetProvided = (arr = [], target) =>
  target ? arr.filter(({ category }) => category === target) : arr;

const items = [ {'name':"A",'category':"a"}, {'name':"B",'category':"b"}, {'name':"C",'category':"c"} ];

console.log( filterByCategoryIfTargetProvided(items) );
console.log( filterByCategoryIfTargetProvided(items, 'a') );
```

Answer (score 2):

This function requires an array and the object you want to filter. You can use it to filter the object based on the category, name or any other object key. Thanks.

```js
let items = [
{ name: "A", category: "a" },
{ name: "B", category: "b" },
{ name: "C", category: "c" },
];

const filterItems = (arr, itemToFilter) => {
if (itemToFilter) {
    const keyToFilter = Object.keys(itemToFilter);
    const filteredItem = arr.filter((eachItem) => {
        return eachItem[keyToFilter] === itemToFilter[keyToFilter];
    });
    return filteredItem;
} else {
    return arr;
}
};

console.log(filterItems(items, { category: "a" }));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).